# Codeigniter pagination links dosnt work after the first page

Tags: codeigniter, search, hyperlink, pagination

i have a search field and i want to show the results with pagination.

every thing works well in first result page but in other pages there is noting to show without any errors and when back to first page also there is noting.

i putted the posted key in session to avoid losing it.

but still noting.

this is my controller:

```
  public function search()
{


    $this->session->set_userdata('searched',$this->input->post('searchterm'));
    $searchterm = $this->session->userdata('searched');
    $limit = ($this->uri->segment(3) > 0)?$this->uri->segment(3):0;

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'home/search';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->home_model->search_record_count($searchterm,$language);
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['display_pages'] = TRUE; 
    $choice = $config['total_rows']/$config['per_page'];
    $config['num_links'] = 3;       
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['results'] = $this->home_model->search($searchterm,$limit,$language);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['searchterm'] = $searchterm;
    $data['total']= $this->home_model->search_record_count($searchterm,$language);      


        putHeader();
        putTop();
        putTopmenu();
        putSearch($data);
        putFooter();
}
```

this is my model:

```
  public function search_record_count($searchterm)
{
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt FROM content WHERE body LIKE '%" .  $searchterm . "%'";
  $q = $this->db->query($sql);
  $row = $q->row(); 
  return $row->cnt;
}

public function search($searchterm,$limit)
{

    $data = $this->db
                    ->select('content.title,content.id,content.category,content.body,path')
                    ->from('content')   
                    ->join('categories','noor_content.category = categories.id')                    
                    ->like('noor_content.title', $searchterm)
                    ->like('noor_content.body', $searchterm)
                    ->limit("5")        
                    ->order_by("content.id","DESC")
                    ->get();

    if($data->num_rows() > 0)
    {

        return $data->result();
        //print_r($data);exit();
    }
    else
    {

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try  `$config['base_url'] = site_url('home/search');`? Enable error report to see the errors

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not limiting your query according to the pagination.  In your controller you are getting the 3rd URL segment

```
$limit = ($this->uri->segment(3) > 0)?$this->uri->segment(3):0;
```

And passing it to you model but then you are not doing anything with it.  In your model you want to do something like

```
$data = $this->db
    ->select('content.title,content.id,content.category,content.body,path')
    ->from('content')   
    ->join('categories','noor_content.category = categories.id')                    
    ->like('noor_content.title', $searchterm)
    ->like('noor_content.body', $searchterm)
    ->limit("10, " . $limit) //Edited this line     
    ->order_by("content.id","DESC")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use method = 'get' instead of post... i mean some thing like this ..

```
<form method="get" action="your_controller/your_function">
   //your search form 
</form>
```

by using get instead of post u dont have to use any session variables and u can easily access them in your controller as

```
$this->input->get('feild_name');
```

moreover u wont have problem with second page or any other page in pagination as all the search feilds get attached in the url and u can access it easily using   `$this->input->get('feild_name');`  untill your url is changes to something else.. i will aslo save u al ot of coding ..